# For OpenGL Shaders, how would you write a Uniform Function in C++ that accepts all types?

Tags: c++, templates, opengl, glsl, shader

So say I have a Shader class and I want to have a Uniform function that sends the data I pass to the loaded Shader program

```cpp
class Shader{
   unsigned int programid;
   template<typename Type>
   void Uniform(unsigned int location, Type object){
       //Some logic that passes the type data to the uniform using glUniform[?]()
   }
}
```

How would I write the Uniform function (using templates in C++) to accept any type (primitive OR object) and pass it to the Shader?

Examples:

GLSL: `uniform float Amount;`
C++: `shader.Uniform(somefloat);`

GLSL: `uniform vec3 Position;`

C++:

```cpp
template<typename Type, size_t Size>
Vector{ Type data[Size]; }

Vector<float, 3> position = {0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}
shader.Uniform(position);
```

GLSL:

```c
struct Light
{
  vec3 position;
  vec4 rotation;
  float luminosity;
  bool status;
};

uniform Light object;
```

C++:

```cpp
struct Light {
  Vector<float, 3> position;
  Vector<float, 4> rotation;
  float luminosity;
  bool status;
}
Light object = {{1.0f,0.0f,0.0f},{0.0f,0.0f,0.0f},0.75f,true};
shader.Uniform(object);
```

Comment: If you were to accept *anything*, how would you know that the shader would be able to handle it? It would need to know how to handle *anything you throw at it*, how could it possibly do that? Magic? How would you expect it to behave when it cannot handle what you throw at it?

Comment: Well I would know what the shader wants beforehand (because I coded it) the Uniform function would just have some logic that routes the type to the correct glUniform function (or multiple function calls for structs/arrays). If I passed something that the shader doesn't accept, it should error internally and not use the passed object.

Comment: Read about [explicit (full) template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). Note, you've to write a separate function, method or specialization for each type, because the OpenGL API provides a different named interface function for each type (`glUniform*`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, C++ and GLSL are statically typed languages, not dynamically typed like JavaScript or Python. So there is no actual way to write a C++ function that accepts any type. What your C++ template function does is, essentially, a text substitution. Every time the C++ compiler sees the template used, eg "Vector", it takes the original template declaration and makes a new copy with "Type" and "Size" replaced by "float" and "3" respectively. And the compiler generates a unique mangled name to prevent linker errors something like __Vector_TypeFOO_SizeBAR...

(For sake of completeness, yes it's possible to implement your own dynamic typing in C/C++ with unions and/or pointer casts. But since you can't do either of those in GLSL, it doesn't help answer the question.)

So, since GLSL doesn't have templates to do the text replacement, you'll have to implement it yourself. Load the source of your shader from file or whatever. Before you pass it to glCompileShader, use your favourite string processing library to insert actual strings into placeholder text.

Eg in your shader you could write something like:

```
<TYPE><SIZE> position;
```

and your main program would do something like

```
src = loadShaderCode("example.template");
src.replace("<TYPE>", "vec");
src.replace("<SIZE>", "3");
shader = compileShader(src, ...);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice idea for a GLSL template system, but I was looking for a system of functions in C++ that could accept any primitive or object or vector and send it to the shader. Something using templates and type comparisons. (I think my question title was a little confusing)

Comment: So you want C++  function(s) that accept a range of C++ types and convert them into the fixed GLSL uniform type?
Simple case of a few floats, say one scalar or a vector of 1 to 4 values, writing the 5 overload variants is probably quicker than figuring out how to template it.
Beyond that, complexity escalates rapidly and it's going to depend very heavily on who uses the code and for what purpose. "Any primitive or object or vector" could strings? B-Trees? OBJ models? Impossible to answer without knowing more

Comment: Yeah, just realized that yesterday. I just went with making all the primitives and vector functions with copy & paste. Using templates for any struct objects would just be impossible w/o reflection.